# why atoi() function from #include<cstdlib> is not working

Tags: c++, string, binary, atoi

I created a program to convert a number into its binary format using a string(r), now I want to convert it into integer data type, I found atoi() function(import from cstdlib) on google for conversion from string to integer but its not working.

Here is my code- it shows error [click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKe2R.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num,n;string r;
    cout<<"Enter the number : ";
    cin>>num;
    while(num!=0){r = (num%2==0?"0":"1")+r;num/=2;}
    cout<<"\nBinary value is "<<r<<endl;
    n = atoi(r);
    cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you tagged c++, I'd check `std::stoi` and maybe `std::from_chars`

Comment: Include the error message *as text, formatted as code* in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi()` expects a `const char *` (an array of `char`), where `r` is a `std::string` object. You can convert a `string` to `const char *` with it's `c_str()` method.

```
atoi(r.c_str())
```

Answer (score 2):

`atoi()` takes char arrays(ex. `char xd[210]`). If you wanna use strings, use `stoi()` instead.